# Bugjar won't run from terminal

Tags: python, ubuntu

I've installed Bugjar on an Ubuntu virtual machine using `pip install bugjar`, but whenever I try to run a python program it says `bugjar: command not found`.  What did I do wrong, and how can I fix it?  There doesn't seem to be any documentation on this, and this is probably the third time I've tried this and gotten the same problem.

Comment: did the pip install succed? if are not running from a virtual environment you should use `sudo pip install bugjar`. but you should really install it in a virtual environment. also there is a dependency to bugjar: https://github.com/pybee/bugjar#problems-under-ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, the pip install succeeded, and I have the dependency.  What do you mean by run it in a virtual environment?  I'm already running it in a virtual machine, you want me to run a virtual machine on my virtual machine?  Shouldn't it just run?

Comment: ok then search for the file bugjar. try `sudo updatedb; locate bugjar | grep bugjar$`. see if you have the file, maybe its just not in your PATH, if so invoking it using the full path name will be required. virtualenv make cleaner python distribution and allow you to reset it from scratch and ensure your environment is reproductible. I guess you can just recreate your vm from scratch in your case and run one VM per python envirnment.